# ORA 29260: network error: TNS:connection closed

Tags: oracle, plsql, sftp, plsql-package

When i try to connect an sftp location from my oracle machine using a PL/SQL procedure, i got the ORA-29260: network error: TNS:connection closed error.

- No problem with telnet connection
- Target sftp machine is added to ACL
- No problem on file transfer using ssh
- Can manually connect to sftp location

```
DECLARE
  l_conn  UTL_TCP.connection;
BEGIN
  l_conn := ftp.login('xx.xx.xx.xx', '22', 'myuser', 'mypass');
--  ftp.ascii(p_conn => l_conn);
--  ftp.put(p_conn      => l_conn,
--          p_from_dir  => 'MY_DOCS',
--          p_from_file => 'test_get.txt',
--          p_to_file   => '/app/test_put.txt
dbms_output.put_line('connection done');
ftp.logout(l_conn);
END;
```

is there any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your program will never work. You are using port 22, which means that you are using `SFTP`, which is built on top of `SSH`. `PLSQL` does not provide an `API` against `SSH` directly from `UTL_TCP`.

However, it can be implemented using `dbms_scheduler` with `external_script`

To use SFTP from PL/SQL I'd do the following.

- Use keypair authentication between the database server and the remote SSH service, allowing passwordless connections.
- Write a shell script to perform the SFTP command.
- Call the shell script from a job using the scheduler.

So, you have a script bash which runs the sftp, assuming you have exchange keys between the hosts that no passwords are needed.

```
#!/bin/bash 

cd /directoryfiles
sftp user@host << eof 
mput *.* -- or mget 
eof
```

This is `mysftp.sh`. Then you need a credential and a job in `dbms_scheduler`

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_CREDENTIAL.create_credential(
    credential_name => 'my_cred_sftp',
    username        => 'myuser',
    password        => 'mypassword'
  );
END;
/

BEGIN
 DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job(
    job_name        => 'MY_RUN_SFTP',
    job_type        => 'EXTERNAL_SCRIPT',
    job_action      => '/mydirectory/mysftp.sh',
    credential_name => 'my_cred_sftp',
    enabled         => TRUE , 
    auto_drop       => TRUE
  );
END;
/
```